# Have tf.layers.dense connected to different inputs OR have tf.train.optimizer optimize tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and more advanced machine learning, so I tried to get a better grasp of RNNs by implementing one by hand instead of using tf.contrib.rnn.RNNCell.  My first problem was that I needed to unroll the net for backpropogation so I looped through my sequence and I needed to keep consistent weights and biases, so I couldn't reinitialize a dense layer with tf.layers.dense each time, but I also needed to have my layer connected to the current timestep of my sequence and I couldn't find a way to change what a dense layer was connected to.  To work around this I tried to implement my own version of tf.layers.dense, and this worked fine until I got the error: NotImplementedError("Trying to update a Tensor " ...) when I tried to optimize my custom dense layers.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import random

# -----------------
# WORD PARAMETERS
# -----------------

target_string = ['Hello ','Hello ','World ','World ', '!']
number_input_words = 1

# --------------------------
# TRAINING HYPERPARAMETERS
# --------------------------

training_steps = 4000
batch_size = 9
learning_rate = 0.01
display_step = 150
hidden_cells = 20

# ----------------------
# PREPARE DATA AS DICT
# ----------------------

# TODO AUTOMATICALLY CREATE DICT
dictionary = {'Hello ': 0, 'World ': 1, '!': 2}
reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
vocab_size = len(dictionary)
# ------------
# LSTM MODEL
# ------------

class LSTM:

    def __init__(self, sequence_length, number_input_words, hidden_cells,     mem_size_x, mem_size_y, learning_rate):

    self.sequence = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (sequence_length, vocab_size), 'sequence')

    self.memory = tf.zeros([mem_size_x, mem_size_y])

    # sequence_length = self.sequence.shape[0]
    units = [vocab_size, 5,4,2,6, vocab_size]
    weights = [tf.random_uniform((units[i-1], units[i])) for i in range(len(units))[1:]]
    biases = [tf.random_uniform((1, units[i])) for i in range(len(units))[1:]]

    self.total_loss = 0
    self.outputs = []

    for word in range(sequence_length-1):
        sequence_w = tf.reshape(self.sequence[word], [1, vocab_size])
        layers = []
        for i in range(len(weights)):
            if i == 0:
                layers.append(tf.matmul(sequence_w, weights[0]) + biases[0])
            else:
                layers.append(tf.matmul(layers[i-1], weights[i]) + biases[i])
        percentages = tf.nn.softmax(logits=layers[-1])
        self.outputs.append(percentages)
        self.total_loss += tf.losses.absolute_difference(tf.reshape(self.sequence[word+1], (1, vocab_size)), tf.reshape(percentages, (1, vocab_size)))

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    self.train_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss=self.total_loss, var_list=weights+biases, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())




lstm = LSTM(len(target_string), number_input_words, hidden_cells, 10, 5, learning_rate)

# ---------------
# START SESSION
# ---------------
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

   sequence = []

    for i in range(len(target_string)):
        x = [0]*vocab_size
        x[dictionary[target_string[i]]] = 1
        sequence.append(x)
        print(sequence)
        for x in range(1000):
            sess.run(lstm.train_operation, feed_dict={lstm.sequence: sequence})
        prediction, loss = sess.run((lstm.outputs, lstm.total_loss), feed_dict=    {lstm.sequence: sequence})
        print(prediction)
        print(loss)
```

Any answers that tell me either how to either connect tf.layers.dense to different variables each time or tell me how to get around my NotImplementedError would be greatly appreciated.  I apologize if this question is lengthy or just badly worded, i'm still new to stackoverflow.

EDIT:

I've updated the LSTM class part of my code to:
(Inside def **init**)

```
    self.sequence = [tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (batch_size, vocab_size), 'sequence') for _ in range(sequence_length-1)]

    self.total_loss = 0
    self.outputs = []

    rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_cells)
    h = tf.zeros((batch_size, hidden_cells))

    for i in range(sequence_length-1):
        current_sequence = self.sequence[i]
        h = rnn_cell(current_sequence, h)
        self.outputs.append(h)
```

But I still get an error on the line: `h = rnn_cell(current_sequence, h)` about not being able to iterate over tensors.  I'm not trying to iterate over any tensors, and if I am I don't mean to.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a standard way of approaching this issue (this is the best approach I know from my knowledge) Instead of trying to create a new list of dense layers. Do the following. Before that lets assume your hidden layer size is `h_dim` and number of steps to unroll is `num_unroll` and batch size `batch_size`

1. In a for loop, you calculate the output of the RNNCell for each unrolled input

`h = tf.zeros(...)
outputs= []
for ui in range(num_unroll):
    out, state = rnn_cell(x[ui],state)
    outputs.append(out)`

2. Now concat all the `outputs` to a single tensor of size, `[batch_size*num_unroll, h_dim]`
3. Send this through a single dense layer of size `[h_dim, num_classes]`

`logits = tf.matmul(tf.concat(outputs,...), w) + b
predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)`

You have the logits for all the unrolled inputs now. Now it's just a matter of reshaping the tensor to a `[batch_size, num_unroll, num_classes]` tensor.

**Edited (Feeding in Data)**: The data will be presented in the form of a list of `num_unroll` many placeholders. So,

`x = [tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size,3]...) for ui in range(num_unroll)]`

Now say you have data like below,

`Hello world bye
Bye hello world`

Here batch size is 2, sequence length is 3. Once converted to one hot encoding, you're data looks like below (shape `[time_steps, batch_size, 3]`.

`data = [ [ [1,0,0], [0,0,1] ], [ [0,1,0], [1,0,0] ], [ [0,0,1], [0,1,0] ] ]`

Now feed data in, in the following format.

`feed_dict = {}
for ui in range(3):
    feed_dict[x[ui]] = data[ui]`

Comment: What is `h.shape`?

Comment: h is the output you get for a single input of the unrolled input sequence. So `h.shape = [batch_size, h_dim]`

Comment: Is `x[ui]` the current index of the sequence? I'm getting an error getting an index of a tensor if it is.

Comment: More Detail: When I run: 
       `rnn_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_cells)
        h = tf.zeros((1, hidden_cells))

        for i in range(sequence_length-1):
            h = rnn_cell(tf.reshape(self.sequence[i],(1, vocab_size)), h)
            self.outputs.append(h)
        
        logits = tf.layers.dense(tf.concat(outputs), 10)`

I get TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn. But when I replace BasicLSTMCell with BasicRNNCell I get ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for ...

Comment: What does your data looks like, the data for the example I put up, I was assuming a list of `num_unroll` inputs and each input is a tensor of size `[batch_size, num_features]`

Comment: I have a list of strings: `['Hello ','Hello ','World ','World ', '!']` Which I one-hot encode into `[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]` Which is passed into the placeholder `lstm.sequence`

Comment: You need to have a list of placeholders (x) instead of one. The list needs `num_unroll` placeholders. Then you can get the i th placeholder with x[i]. At every step of unroll, you need to fill in all the placeholder in that list.

Comment: EDIT: I'm confused about what would go in that list of placeholders

Comment: I'm still running into an error, I've updated my question.

Comment: This is because, LSTMCell returns two elements; output and the state. This line (`h = rnn_cell(current_sequence, h)`) need to change to `out, state = rnn_cell(current_sequence, state)` and then do `outputs.append(out)` I've updated the code as well.

Comment: I've changed `h = tf.zeros((batch_size, hidden_cells))` to state = tf.zeros((batch_size, hidden_cells)) and `h = rnn_cell(current_sequence, h) to `out, state = rnn_cell(current_sequence, state)`, but I still get the same error about iterating over a tensor.